# SQL server get start date for an end date record that is not leading or lagging

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a finger print system
which have several columns
User, Device, Mode, Activity time

the user is the employee
the device are 2 devices one is outdoor for outsiders and one is indoor for insiders
Activity which contain several modes 
F1:Leave\Attend
F2:Break
F3:Work leave
F4:Personal Leave
F5:Smoking Leave

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.UserActivity (
 [User] int NOT NULL,
 Mode varchar(6) NOT NULL,
 Activity varchar(6) NOT NULL,
 ActivityTime datetime NOT NULL
) 
GO

--Insert data into the UserActivity table
INSERT dbo.UserActivity ([User] ,Mode , Activity, ActivityTime) 
VALUES (1,'F1' ,'Divout', CAST('2013-01-01 08:30' AS datetime))
, (1,'F3' ,'Divin', CAST('2013-01-01 10:45' AS datetime))
, (1,'F3' ,'Divout', CAST('2013-01-01 13:15' AS datetime))
, (1,'F5' ,'Divin', CAST('2013-01-01 15:30' AS datetime))
, (1,'F3' ,'Divin', CAST('2013-01-01 16:15' AS datetime))
, (1,'F3' ,'Divout', CAST('2013-01-01 17:00' AS datetime))
, (1,'F1' ,'Divout', CAST('2013-01-02 08:30' AS datetime))
, (1,'F3' ,'Divin', CAST('2013-01-02 10:45' AS datetime))
, (1,'F4' ,'Divout', CAST('2013-01-02 13:00' AS datetime))
, (1,'F1' ,'Divin', CAST('2013-01-02 16:45' AS datetime))
, (2,'F1' ,'Divout', CAST('2013-01-01 8:25' AS datetime))
, (2,'F3' ,'Divin', CAST('2013-01-01 11:30' AS datetime))
, (2,'F3' ,'Divout', CAST('2013-01-01 12:35' AS datetime))
, (2,'F1' ,'Divin', CAST('2013-01-01 14:45' AS datetime))
```

I did well ordering events which everyone when its start and end
I handled also some error 
1-if the same device used twice in a row  then its error "cause when you print from inside you should print from outside in return"
2- if the start Activity doesn't match end activity then error "if you print F2 mode then in return you must print F2 mode"

this is my code:

```
select *,Error_Column=CASE 
                      WHEN ((Lag(T2.Activity, 1)OVER(ORDER BY T2.[UserName],T2.EndActivityTime,T2.CurrentMode)=T2.Activity)--2 finger prints from same device
                       or ((T2.PreviousMode<>T2.CurrentMode) and (T2.PreviousMode is not null or T2.CurrentMode is not Null)))--inside mode differenet than outside mode
                      then 1
                      else 0
                      end
 from (

SELECT Activity --Device Place
,CurrentMode=Mode --Device Mode
, PreviousMode = --Inter F
     CASE 
     WHEN Activity='Divout' --UserName was out and he return
     THEN  Lag([Mode], 1) OVER(ORDER BY [User],ActivityTime,Mode) --give me his last leave state
     Else Null --Else UserName using inside so we don't need his last leave state
     End
, ActivityDate = CAST(ActivityTime As DATE) --Date of Activity
, UserName = [User] --UserName
, EndActivityTime = ActivityTime
, StartActivityTime = 
    CASE 
    WHEN Activity='Divout' --UserName was out and he return
    THEN Lag(ActivityTime, 1) OVER(ORDER BY [User], ActivityTime,Mode)
     Else Null
     End
, EndActivityDate = CAST(ActivityTime AS DATE)
, StartActivityDate = 
    CASE 
    WHEN Activity='Divout' --UserName was out and he return
    Then CAST(Lag(ActivityTime, 1) OVER(ORDER BY [User], ActivityTime ,Mode) AS DATE)
     Else Null
     End
FROM dbo.UserActivity
where mode<>'F1'

Union 

SELECT Activity --Device Place
,CurrentMode=Mode --Device Mode
, PreviousMode = --Inter F
     CASE 
     WHEN Activity='Divin' --End of the Day
     THEN  Lag([Mode], 1) OVER(ORDER BY [User],ActivityTime,Mode) --give me his Attendance Mode
     Else Null --Else UserName using outside so we don't need his last leave state
     End
, ActivityDate = CAST(ActivityTime As DATE) --Date of Activity
, UserName = [User] --UserName
, EndActivityTime = ActivityTime
, StartActivityTime = 
    CASE 
    WHEN Activity='Divin' 
    THEN Lag(ActivityTime, 1) OVER(ORDER BY [User], ActivityTime,Mode)
     Else Null
     End
, EndActivityDate = CAST(ActivityTime AS DATE)
, StartActivityDate = 
    CASE 
    WHEN Activity='Divin' 
    Then CAST(Lag(ActivityTime, 1) OVER(ORDER BY [User], ActivityTime,Mode) AS DATE)
     Else Null
     End
FROM (select * from  dbo.UserActivity where mode='F1') T1)T2
ORDER BY T2.[UserName],T2.EndActivityTime,T2.CurrentMode
```

the problem I faced is there are some special cases that I couldn't find the way to handle 
E.g. when you are "F3: work leave" .. it may you will not return back to work
in this case F1 will be closed by F3.. also sometime you may take a personal leave before the end of the workday with 1 hour .. so yo will print F4
in this case F1 will be closed by F4.

I thought a lot of how should I handle those 2 cases in my code but I couldn't reach a solution for it

anyone can help me handle them... 
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using SQL Server, or Oracle?

Comment: Your code looks like SQL Server so I removed the Oracle tag.

Comment: ya SQL server .. I Just needed any help from a DB devopers

Comment: Mistagging databases is not the way to get it. You attract good attention by tagging correctly.

Comment: You should to learn [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Dump your tables and code  is not the way, instead to copy-paste your development environment here you should to create a small snipped just with your issue, one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to suggest that you need to use **PARTITION BY** in your logic. For example:

> ```
> select
>     *
> from (
>     select
>           CAST(ActivityTime AS date) act_date
>         , row_number() over(partition by [User], CAST(ActivityTime AS date)
>                             order by ActivityTime ASC)                     start_row
>         , row_number() over(partition by [User], CAST(ActivityTime AS date)
>                             order by ActivityTime DESC)                    end_row
>         , [User]
>         , Mode
>         , Activity
>         , ActivityTime
>     from UserActivity
>     ) d
> order by act_date, [User], start_row
> ;
> ```

Below, between start_row 1 and end_row 1, you can see the full sequence of activity per day per user. I think it will make it easier to apply your business logic once you have these boundaries established.

> ```
> act_date   | start_row | end_row | User | Mode | Activity | ActivityTime       
> :----------|-----------|-------- | -----|------|----------|--------------------
> 01/01/2013 | 1         | 6       |    1 | F1   | Divout   | 01/01/2013 08:30:00
> 01/01/2013 | 2         | 5       |    1 | F3   | Divin    | 01/01/2013 10:45:00
> 01/01/2013 | 3         | 4       |    1 | F3   | Divout   | 01/01/2013 13:15:00
> 01/01/2013 | 4         | 3       |    1 | F5   | Divin    | 01/01/2013 15:30:00
> 01/01/2013 | 5         | 2       |    1 | F3   | Divin    | 01/01/2013 16:15:00
> 01/01/2013 | 6         | 1       |    1 | F3   | Divout   | 01/01/2013 17:00:00
>
> 01/01/2013 | 1         | 4       |    2 | F1   | Divout   | 01/01/2013 08:25:00
> 01/01/2013 | 2         | 3       |    2 | F3   | Divin    | 01/01/2013 11:30:00
> 01/01/2013 | 3         | 2       |    2 | F3   | Divout   | 01/01/2013 12:35:00
> 01/01/2013 | 4         | 1       |    2 | F1   | Divin    | 01/01/2013 14:45:00
>
> 02/01/2013 | 1         | 4       |    1 | F1   | Divout   | 02/01/2013 08:30:00
> 02/01/2013 | 2         | 3       |    1 | F3   | Divin    | 02/01/2013 10:45:00
> 02/01/2013 | 3         | 2       |    1 | F4   | Divout   | 02/01/2013 13:00:00
> 02/01/2013 | 4         | 1       |    1 | F1   | Divin    | 02/01/2013 16:45:00
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d654f1da8fbb8a99bd0264549a003d79)*

Comment: Hi ,, Thanx for respond... but do you notice row 2 he printed f3 from inside.. so the start was in row 2... but the end I think should be in row 3 because he came back and he printed f3 on the outside device .. you can make sure of that that the time 10:45 will end at 13:15

Comment: You need to define your rules clearly. And you should display the "expected result". I don't see "printed from inside" in the data. What does **divout** mean?. How can the earliest record in a day not be the start? These are things you should explain in the question.